# Updating UI from Scheduled Service

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm using an AlarmManager to start periodically a Service to retrieve data from server:

```
    alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, Service.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 1, intent, 0);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(
            AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
            SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(),
            AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES,
            pendingIntent);
```

So It launches and everything goes well...

The only problem is that I don't know how to update the main UI from it... All the examples I've seen don't use AlarmManager... so they don't fit my needs.

Could you please help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

your service will no have access to the UI thread. But it is possible to use the Context Object you have a references to in your code to call

```
runOnUiThread(Runnable Action);
```

If your familar with Runnable and other mutlithreading capability then you get where I'm going with this.

Otherwise,

Have your service fire off Intent broadcasts and create a nested class that extends BroadcastReceiver

```
private class updateUIReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
```

inside the Activity that currently holds your UI thread. Then get creative using

```
Intent.putExtra();
```

to tell your activity how to update the UI. Such as strings are ints. Constants work well.